# Meteor get blank data from collection

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

i am using Meteor 1.4 and i'm trying to get data from data base collection but i got blank array .
This is my code

**Server side**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Employee = new Mongo.Collection('employee');
```

**Client Side**

```
import { Employee } from '/imports/api/employee/employee.js';
Template.employee.helpers({
employee_list: function() {
    var emp = Employee.find().fetch();
    console.log('emp', emp);
});
```

i successfully insert into same collection but if i try to get data than it's blank.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the collection or are you running autosubscribe?

Comment: no i am not using subscribe and publish

Comment: In which case, The collection will not be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor works with pub/sub model, and, if the client is not subscribed to the collection, updates will not be propagated to it.